# Why i cant install saiku in pentaho server 8.2

Tags: server, pentaho, saiku

when i try to install saiku analitycs from market place only apear the Enterprise Edition. When i try to install it gave me an error. And the estable version that can donwload do not apear in the market place.

[image]

Comment: haven't checked with recent version but some version back they were giving both the options and some changes of installing certificates for community version. It is possible that they have stopped providing saiku for new versions.

Answer (score 0):

you can download saiku from below link

https://community.hitachivantara.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.meteorite.bi%2Fdownloads%2Fsaiku-plugin-p7.1-3.90.zip

unzip the file, copy the folder and paste into below location

> pentaho-server\pentaho-solutions\system

restart the pentaho BI server.
after starting the server you will see saiku analytics under create new..!!!!

Once you will click for the first time it will show you the pop-up follow the instructions.